# "where" on iterable with async test

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Am I missing an integrated functionality of the dart language (or a lightweight library) to do what `where()` does on iterables, only with an `async` test? I'm currently using my own implementation:

```
  Future<Iterable<T>> whereAsync<T>(
      Iterable<T> collection, Future<bool> Function(T) asyncTest) async {
    Map<T, bool> mappedCollection = Map();
    await Future.wait(collection.map((element) async =>
        mappedCollection[element] = await asyncTest(element)));
    return mappedCollection.entries
        .where((entry) => entry.value)
        .map((entry) => entry.key);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you code example looks a more complicated than it needs to be. Also, you should try read something about Streams since they are the async version of iterator.

I have tried to make my own version of you code which I think solves the same problem:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  final list = [1, 2, 3];

  whereAsync(Stream.fromIterable(list), (e) => e != 2).forEach(print); // 1 3
}

Stream<T> whereAsync<T>(Stream<T> stream, FutureOr<bool> check(T input)) async* {
  await for (var element in stream) {
    if (await check(element)) {
      yield element;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is missing the point of obtaining the filtered `Iterable` in one piece, which would require collecting the checked elements in your `await for` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code posed in the question indexes into a map using the elements of the `Iterable`, it will suffer from a potential defect when two or more elements are equal.

Here's a method which is simpler and doesn't exhibit the potential defect.

```
class Pair<T1, T2> {
  final T1 first;
  final T2 second;

  Pair(this.first, this.second);
}

Future<Iterable<T>> whereAsync<T>(Iterable<T> items, Future<bool> Function(T) test) async {
  final futures = items.map((e) => test(e).then((v) => Pair(e, v)));
  final results = await Future.wait(futures);
  return results.where((e) => e.second).map((e) => e.first);
}
```